How is $2^A$ the power set of $A$?
I'm reading Naive Set Theory by Paul H. Halmos and there's something that has been bugging me for a while. In the book, Halmos seems to assume $2^A=\mathscr P(A)$, and I don't quite understand the reason.
Here's what I understood: if you construct natural numbers as sets, you'll have that $2=\{0,1\}$ and thus $2^A$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$. It makes sense to consider an element of $2^A$ as analogous to a subset of $A$, since you can easily create a bijection between the two: given any $f\in 2^A$, $E=\{x\in A\mid f(x)=1\}$ is a subset of $A$.
But they are not the same set, they just have the same cardinality, right?

Some people just use that as formal notation:  it doesn't always mean the set of maps from $A$ to $2$.

I would also say it's a bit stronger than they just have the same cardinality:  there is a very natural isomorphism between the two.

I agree with you OP. What has the author said is the definition of $2^A?$

A subset can be identified as a function that says whether or not an element of the superset is a member of the subset. This is done a lot in mathematics. We can view $\mathbb R^n$, for example, as the set of real valued functions from ${1,\dots, n}$.

I'm reading Halmos right now, and he never says they are equal.  He says they are in natural one-to-one correspondence, which is exactly what you said.  You actually don't disagree with him at all.

This discussion appears on page 33 of section 8 in the first edition.  There, he says that the function that assigns to each subset $A$ of $X$ the characteristic function $\chi_A : X \to 2$ is a "one-to-one correpondence between $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $2^X$."  This does not mean that he asserts that they are equal (though in practice it will make little difference precisely because of this natural correspondence).
There are several spots in the text where he writes "$\mathcal{P}(A)$ is equivalent to $2^A$ " [see page 100 of section 25] but again this is exactly the meaning of "they are in one-to-one correspondence."  Equivalent doesn't mean equal.
